# Contour Integral of $\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1+a\cos\theta}$ for $a^2<1$ (textbook wrong?)

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

My book is telling me that the answer is $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$. I'm getting an extra a on the numerator. Could somebody verify if I'm wrong, or if it's my book (it has been wrong numerous times).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The textbook answer is correct. You maybe omitted some factor somewhere, can you do a re-check? Note that if you take $a=0$, your answer does not give the right value.

Comment: If I am, I'm not seeing it. I'm getting a pole at $\frac{-1+\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}$, leading to a residue of $\frac{a}{2\sqrt{1-a^2}}$. Multiplying this by $2 \pi i *-2 i$ provides me with the result I posted. Which is wrong: all of them?

Comment: Note that the denominator (after replacing the $\cos$) reads $1+a(z+1/z)/2$ ($z=\exp(I \theta)$). It is easier if you pull out $a$ as common factor, so the coefficient of $z^2$ in the denominator is $1$. Now , one has $1/a$ pre-factor.

Comment: I was just considering trying that. What I did was I kept it as is, multiplied the numerator and denominator both by 2, and got the denominator as $az^2+2z+a$. Setting this equal to zero yields the work that I put in my above comment (I kept that pole since the other one was outside of the unit disk). Can you spot the mistake if I keep it? I've checked multiple time that I found the poles correctly. I don't see how that a factor will go away.

Comment: The integral reads as a circle integral in the complex plane, going around $0$ anti-clockwise: $\oint dz/(Iz)\frac{1}{1+a\frac{z+1/z}{2}}$   or  $$\frac{2}{Ia}\oint \frac{dz}{z^2+\frac{2}{a}z+1}$$. The pole is $-1/a+\sqrt{1/a^2-1}$. This should clear it.

Comment: Right, I'm getting the same pole, except that I'm writing it in a different form. Hm. So, if I'm getting the same pole, then why is my answer different? I'm solving $-2i\oint\frac{dz}{az^2+2z+a}$. My pole is the same as yours-you just brought up the "a" factor into the square root.

Comment: I guess the way you compute the residue is not correct. The denominator can be given as $a(z-z_0)(z-z_1)$, where $z_0$ is the pole that contributes to the integral and the other root reads $z_1=-1/a-\sqrt{1/a^2-1}$. The residues theorem gives us $-2i 2\pi \, i/ [a(z_0-z_1)] = 2\pi/\sqrt{1-a^2}$.

Comment: Ah, I see it now! I didn't have that a when I factored in the residue. I just factored it like $(z-z_0)(z-z_1)$ in my head, which of course I can't do, since the $z^2$ term has a co-efficient. I missed that. Thanks for the help and being so patient!

Answer (score 4):

**Contour Integration**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{1+a\cos(\theta)}
&=\oint\frac{2\,\mathrm{d}z}{iz\left(2+az+\frac az\right)}\tag{1}\\
&=-\frac{2i}a\oint\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2+\frac2az+1}\tag{2}\\
&=-\frac{2i}a\oint\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\left(z+\frac1a+\sqrt{\frac1{a^2}-1}\right)\left(z+\frac1a-\sqrt{\frac1{a^2}-1}\right)}\tag{3}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $z=e^{i\theta}$
$(2)$: algebra
$(3)$: factor the denominator
$(4)$: the residue of the integrand at $z=-\frac1a+\sqrt{\frac1{a^2}-1}$ is $\frac1{2\sqrt{\frac1{a^2}-1}}$
$\phantom{(4)\text{:}}$ the singularity at $z=-\frac1a-\sqrt{\frac1{a^2}-1}$ is outside the unit circle

---

**Weierstrass Substitution**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{1+a\cos(\theta)}
&=2\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{1+a\cos(\theta)}\tag{5}\\
&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\frac{2\,\mathrm{d}z}{1+z^2}}{1+a\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}}\tag{6}\\
&=4\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{(1+a)+(1-a)z^2}\tag{7}\\
&=\frac4{1+a}\sqrt{\frac{1+a}{1-a}}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{1+z^2}\tag{8}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(5)$: periodicity and evenness of $\cos(x)$
$(6)$: [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)
$(7)$: algebra
$(8)$: substitute $z\mapsto\sqrt{\frac{1+a}{1-a}}\,z$

Answer (score 3):

For small $a$,

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1+a\cos(\theta)}\approx\int_0^{2\pi}(1-a\cos(\theta)+a^2\cos^2(\theta)-a^3\cos^3(\theta))\,d\theta=2\pi\left(1-\frac{a^2}2\right),$$

which is quite compatible with $$\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}.$$

---

Working backwards, the Taylor development of the exact function will give you the integrals of the even powers of the cosine.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thank you.